# MapReduce functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am working on a spark project on eclipse IDE using scala

i would like some help with this MapReduce problem

Map function:

1. remove column 'sport' and 'bourse'
2. delete any row that has 'NULL'
3. Add a new column duration cycle. This will have to take a value according to the cycle of the student: license (3 years), Master (3 years), Ingeniorat (5 years) and doctorate (3 years)

Reducer:

1. add up all the students according to year,cycle and speciality.

my input is

matricule,dateins,cycle,specialite,bourse,sport

0000000001,1999-11-22,Master,IC,Non,Non

0000000002,2014-02-01,Null,IC,Null,Oui

0000000003,2006-09-07,Null,Null,Oui,Oui

0000000004,2008-12-11,Master,IC,Oui,Oui

0000000005,2006-06-07,Master,SI,Non,Oui

0000000006,1996-11-16,Ingeniorat,SI,Null,Null

and so on.

This is the code im starting with. I have removed colomn 'sport' 'bourse' and extracted the year

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   val x = sc.textFile("/home/amel/one")
  val re = x.map(_.split(",")).foreach(r => println(r(1).dropRight(6), r(2),r(3)))
```

this is the result i got

(2000,Licence,Isil)

(2001,Master,SSI)

The result I want is:

year cycle duration speciality Nbr-students

(2000,Licence,3 years,Isil,400)

(2001,Master,3 years,SSI,120)

// I want the column 'Nbr-students' to be the number of students from each year according to their cycle and speciality.

Comment: I don't find this to be a MapReduce-relevant question (you might have used MR previously but this problem itself is not necessarily geared towards MR specifically), so I have removed the MapReduce tag from your question as we do not use MapReduce to solve this problem and no MapReduce code is included in the description.

Comment: I have used a Map function to split my text file. What do you mean this doesn't require mapreduce function? I'm telling you I created a similar project as this. I'm just having trouble with clearing out any row that contains NULLS

Comment: You have used the map function within Apache-Spark to split your text file. You have not used MapReduce code here, as MapReduce is a framework built with Mappers and Reducers. You are mapping data from one form to another.

Comment: oh, now I understand. Well is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I am currently working on a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want the year - if you do not want year, change `cols(1).split("-")(0)` to just `cols(1)`.

First I have faked some data using your sample data:

```scala
val x = sc.parallelize(Array(
  "001,2000-12-22,License,Isil,no,yes",
  "002,2001-11-30,Master,SSI,no,no",
  "003,2001-11-30,Master,SSI,no,no",
  "004,2001-11-30,Master,SSI,no,no",
  "005,2000-12-22,License,Isil,no,yes"
))
```

Next I have done some RDD transformations. First I remove and create the necessary columns, and then I add a count of 1 to each row. Finally, I reduceByKey to count all of the rows with the same information:

```scala
val re = x.map(row => {
  val cols = row.split(",")
  val cycle = cols(2)
  val years = cycle match {
    case "License" => "3 years"
    case "Master" => "3 years"
    case "Ingeniorat" => "5 years"
    case "Doctorate" => "3 years"
    case _ => "other"
  }
  (cols(1).split("-")(0) + "," + years + "," + cycle + "," + cols(3), 1)
}).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

```scala
re.collect.foreach(println)
```

```
(2000,3 years,License,Isil,2)
(2001,3 years,Master,SSI,3)
```

Comment: yes my data is separated by commas. I just tried to make my data more readable for you

Comment: I believe you have forgot the reduceByKey function

Comment: Included :) @Amelha

Comment: That is because of the format of your data. I will need to see copy/pasted examples of the actual data (not changing out commas for spaces) for the rows that have less than three columns of data.

Comment: please check. I have edited my question and included the input exactly how it is

Comment: I have changed the split from space to comma. Try now :) @Amelha